# Glitch in the Java Scalr Library, scaling down is not happening properly for certain images

Tags: java, imgscalr, scalr

Java Scalr Library supports two scaling format s,xy,100,auto and s,x,100,y,auto, but scaling is failing for certain images in either of these format and returning a broken image with 200 success message.

Example -

```
image_url_one/s,x,100,y,auto - Works fine
image_url_one/s,xy,100,auto - Doesn’t work
image_url_one/s,xy,99,auto - Works fine
```

again

```
image_url_two/s,x,100,y,auto - Doesn’t work
image_url_two/s,xy,100,auto - Works fine
image_url_two/s,x,99,y,auto - Works fine
```

Is this a version sepecific issue or it's scalr library issue. can anyone help please?